# anagram search without functions

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, anagram

my code at C ,soupose yo chk for anagrams and can't use functions.
 (we can assume that there's no similiar words) and count it.
the string from the user is up to 1000 chars
what i need to do?

tnx for all helpers.

I've been asked to doalso  other things but i handle it.
this is the code i wrote
maybe just the first part is relevnt to the anagram
    //0// - declraions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SIZE 1001

void main() {//main

                                //declaring vars.
char str[SIZE], temp;
//i,j are global index 
int i, j = 0;
/*location in the string of the ' ' & the tab.      \0 is 4 breaking loop at 
section \\C_2\\ */
int loc_str[SIZE] = { '\0' };
//a,b are index 4 swap
int a, b;

//par b
int c, d, len, n,x, b_g_c=0,sum=0;
int **arr;



//A// wrk on the rvrs strng
//prnt msg 4 user, getting sentence & rvrs it
printf_s("Please enter the sentence, and then press Enter:\n");
gets_s(str, sizeof(str));
printf_s("\n");
len = strlen(str);
n = ceil(sqrt(len));

// Create dynamic array
arr = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
for (c = 0; c <= n; c++)
    arr[c] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
// init array - matrix nXn with ASCII code of the sentence
for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
        arr[c][d] = '\0';

i = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        if (str[i] == '\0') break;
        for (d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            arr[c][d] = str[i];
            i++;
            if (str[i] == '\0') break;
        }

}


strcpy_s(str, sizeof(str), _strrev(str));

//B// srch spaces
//srch ' ' & tab in the sentece & keep it loac. in arr
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {//for
    if ((str[i] == ' ') || (str[i] == ' ')) {//if
                //swap tab at ' '
        if (str[i] == ' ')str[i] = ' ';
        loc_str[j] = i;     //saving the index
        j++;
    }//if
}//for
//save the last index
loc_str[j] = i;

//C_1// swaping
//do the 1st swap myself    //intlizng a & b with the' ' indexes
a = 0;
b = loc_str[0];
for (a; a < b; a++) {//for 1st swap
    temp = str[a];
    str[a] = str[b - 1];
    str[b - 1] = temp;
    b--;
}//for 1st swap

 //C_2// continue swaping
//letting CPU do the rst
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {//for all swaps
    a = loc_str[j];     //intlizng a & b with the next ' ' indexes
    b = loc_str[j + 1];
    if (b == '\0')break;        //saving CPU
    for (a += 1; a < b; a++) {//for local swaping
        temp = str[a];
        str[a] = str[b - 1];
        str[b - 1] = temp;
        b--;
    }//for local swaping
}//for all swaps
//prnt the new sentence 2 user
printf_s("The reverse sentence is:\n%s\n", str);



printf_s("The maximum number of anagram words in this sentence is.\n");


/*for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {//for
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
        (!d) ? printf_s("%d", arr[c][d]) : printf_s("%8d", arr[c][d]);
    printf_s("\n");
}

    printf_s("/nBiggest in their row : .");
    printf_s("/nBiggest in their column :%d.", b_g_c);
```

*/
    }//main

Comment: It is not clear where your actual problem is. Please narrow-down your question.

Comment: EDITED.in one word: anagram.

Comment: Anagrams are funny.  You *REALLY* can't validate them without a dictionary.

Comment: nonsense, i wrote a psoedo code that soupuse to do the work, but i didnt debbuged it